# IDA vs CE Disassembly View

Tags: assembly, ida, cheat-engine

I am using CE to view the assembly of a program and I easily get the needed address: `00B2356E`. This is from the esp, 8.

[CE View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjUF1.png)

When I go into IDA (within the exact same area)

```
.text:0044354B loc_44354B:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_4430A0+48Ej
.text:0044354B                 mov     ecx, 0FAh
.text:00443550                 mov     esi, offset buf
.text:00443555                 lea     edi, [ebp+var_3FC]
.text:0044355B                 rep movsd
.text:0044355D                 push    offset aVersion ; "Version"
.text:00443562                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_3FC]
.text:00443568                 push    eax
.text:00443569                 call    sub_469090
.text:0044356E                 add     esp, 8
```

I cannot find the `00B2356E`address in IDA. How would I be able to do so?

When I subtract and get that ID:0x0072356E

I am put here

```
.data:0072356E db    ? ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the program you're disassembling uses dynamic bases (also known as ASLR) Cheat Engine will show you the "real" address, however, IDA shows it as 0x400000 is the base. To get to the point in memory you are looking for in IDA (in this case `0x00B2356E`), do: `0x00B2356E - Process Base + 0x400000` then jump to that address in IDA.